# How can I combining many external Javascript scripts into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, pagespeed

I check my website using gtmetrix and my website is recommended for fewer HTTP requests and reduce DNS lookups. So I must to combining combining many external Javascript scripts into one

In my layout default like this

For css :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/content/assets/img/favicon.ico">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/libs/materialize/css/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/css/swiper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/assets/style/style.min.css?v=@currentVersion">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/assets/style/style-responsive.min.css?v=@currentVersion">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/assets/style/custom-form-materialize.css">
<link href="/Content/dist/social-share/sharetastic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/assets/style/happy.min.css?v=@currentVersion">
```

For js :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/Content/dist/social-share/sharetastic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/assets/script/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/libs/materialize/js/materialize.min.js?v=@currentVersion"></script>
    <script src="/Content/assets/script/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/js/swiper.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

    <script src="/Content/assets/script/rendercomponent.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/assets/script/script.min.js?v=@currentVersion"></script>
    <script src="/Content/assets/script/share-content.js?v=@currentVersion"></script>
    <script src="/Content/assets/script/jcanvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Content/assets/script/happy.min.js?v=@currentVersion" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I combining many external Javascript scripts into one?

If combining them into one won't impact the website? JS and CSS websites are not problematic?

Comment: You're looking for a bundler, maybe Webpack?

Comment: @CertainPerformance No. My website using sitecore cms

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @Jared Smith It's asp.net. Seems it can not implement in the c#

Comment: @SuccessMan I may not be a C#/ASP.NET developer, but I do [know how to use google search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQ5Kr8uM0yR9cyeEjcOyaF9jiQ_3Q%3A1568380967787&source=hp&ei=J5h7XdncLay8ggeMrIS4BQ&q=sitecore+cms+bundle+files&oq=sitecore+cms+bundle+files&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1531.1531..2571...0.0..0.147.249.0j2......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....10..35i362i39.O2pv-XP4sVY&ved=0ahUKEwiZjNKz8s3kAhUsnuAKHQwWAVcQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)...

Answer (score 0):

Success Man's comment is the correct answer. Webpack or another bundler will allow you to combine js files and reduce the number of requests.

Comment: can it be implemented into sitecore cms?

Comment: You should be able to. You might look at https://asmagin.com/2016/10/10/how-to-marry-reactjs-and-sitecore-with-webpack/